# How to plot a quadratic function in Matlab (with differently scaled axes)

Tags: matlab, plot, quadratic

I am trying to create a plot of a root function with 2 differently scaled axes, so let's say the x axis goes from 0 to 1.2 with steps of 0.1 and the y axis goes from 0 to 1.4 with steps of 0.2 (one function, 2 differently scaled axes). I think I got the scaling correct, please correct me if there is a better way to program this.

Here is my code:

```
x = linspace(0,1.2);
y = 0.5 + (0.9 * (x.^2 - 0.0432)).^(1/2);

% here I need the negative part as well: 0.5 - [...] as follows:
% y2 = 0.5 - (0.9 * (x.^2 - 0.0432)).^(1/2); 
% How can I create this function and plot it?

plot(x,y)
axis([0 1.2 0 1.4])
set(gca,'xTick',0:0.1:1.2)
set(gca,'yTick',0:0.2:1.4)

grid on
```

I have the upper part of the function, but not the lower one (negative one, see above comment in code). How can it be created? Or if that's not possible, how can I create the graph out of differently defined 'subgraphs'? The domain somehow needs to be restricted to x >= 0.206.

Comment: Please read the documentation for the functions you are trying to use. To start, [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) accepts multiple input data series (e.g. `plot(x, y, x, y2);`). The documentation also links you to [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html), which retains plots in the current axes so that new plots added to the axes do not delete existing plots

Comment: The interesting part here is what you actually want to plot this. Note that this function does not belong to the real numbers for given range. Numbers between [0,206) is purely imaginary. So if you want to plot this in 2D you will get something like this. If this is not good enough there are different ways to represent complex numbers. You will have to specify how you want to do it.

Comment: You could not find the function to obtain the [`real`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) component of a complex number?

Comment: 0.0432 is not enough real range [0.206,inf) (ish). And restricting domain of a function is something you do yourself. Now you set the domain to [0,1.2]. A function requiring a function handle may set the domain to all possible values and so on... There is no general rule for this and since matlab works numerically (mostly) this kind of sets the conditions. Further, the question is not very clear. What does 2 differently scaled axes mean? 2 functions - 2 y-axes, 1 function - 2 y-axes, 1 function where x-axis and y-axis have different scaling? Or do you just want to ask if your code is correct?

Comment: @patrik Sorry, I meant 1 function where x-axis and y-axis have different scaling. Also what I wanted to say was `x >= 0.206` instead of `x >= 0.0432`. I'd like to plot the parabola for this domain. The above code is incomplete, as it misses the lower (negative) part of the function.

Comment: Then I guess that your code does what you want. If you find out at which point the function becomes complex, you can probably plot the domain where the function is real. I am not sure how I can help. As stated, the function is not very clear and it rather feels as if you want us to validate your attempt. Please **edit** the post with a clearly stated question.

Comment: I tried to explain what I am trying to achieve. I still don't know how to plot the complete root function for the domain `x >= 0.0432` correctly. My code doesn't do that, did you ever run it?

Comment: Yeah I worked with the inverse first. Wrong term, my bad. Edited in the original post.

Comment: `sqrt(f(x)), f(x) = a*x^2+b*x+c` will not give you a parabola I am afraid. try to plot the range [-10,10] and se how it looks. The values between (-0.206,0.206) will be corrupted due to earlier stated issue. Otherwise the function will act fairly linear. And yes your example run on my machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97425/discussion-between-patrik-and-user3032689).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close!  I would do the following. See comments in code below:

```
n = 1000;                % number of points. More points, smoother 
                         % looking piecewise linear approx. of curve

x0 = sqrt(.0432)+eps;    % Choose smallest xvalue to be at or epsilon to the right
                         % of the apex of the parabola

x = linspace(x0, 1.2, n)';   %'  transpose so x is a column vector (more convenient)
y_pos = 0.5 + (0.9 * (x.^2 - 0.0432)).^(1/2); % positive branch of parabola
y_neg = 0.5 - (0.9 * (x.^2 - 0.0432)).^(1/2); % negative branch of parabola

plot(x,[y_pos, y_neg],'blue')  % we´re graphing two series but use 'blue'
                               % for both so it looks like one series!
axis([0 1.2 0 1.4])
set(gca,'xTick',0:0.1:1.2)
set(gca,'yTick',0:0.2:1.4)

grid on
```

Comment: Corrected typo. I was going to use more points (`n=1000`)  but my first posting didn't pass `n` to linspace.

Comment: Edited for better code highlighting. (a single `'` makes everything which follows colored as a single string)